# nginx on laravel project doesn't work and give 502 bad gateway error

Tags: laravel, macos, nginx, laravel-blade, nginx-config

i am trying to setup nginx on my laptop (MacOS Sonoma 14.0 M1) with my laravel project but i have multiple problem with that.

the first problem that I actually notice is that if i type localhost:8080 i don't see the nginx welcome page but, instead, if i type localhost:8080/ i can see it.

Here is my /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf file

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  gzip on;

  server {
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
      root   /Users/ilpanzer/Desktop/WebPills;
      index index.html index.htm index.html inde.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_n$
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9080;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
        }

  }
 include servers/*;
}
```

and here is my /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/servers/bwa file (the one that should be attached to my laravel project)

```
erver {

    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name bwa.localhost;
    root  /Users/ilpanzer/Desktop/WebPills/bwa_rework/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9074;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and finally this is my env file in my laravel project

```
APP_NAME="BWA Rework"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:VI++nXaNdSG6kYlpjHSRNFpvFuu6HlSBtzSgsPbd1Fg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=bwa.localhost

APP_LOCALE=it
APP_LOCALE_COUNTRY=it_IT
APP_ALLOWED_LANGS=en,es,fr
APP_FRONT_LANGS=en,es,fr
APP_POPUP_ACTIVE=true

LOG_CHANNEL=daily
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bwaDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD="xxxxxxx" //psw is into "" because have special character 

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

APP_LOGO_WHITE="/assets/img/svg/logo_white.svg"
APP_LOGO_BLACK="/assets/img/svg/logo_black.svg"

BOAT_TO_DRAG_HP_ID=6
```

i am pretty sure that everythings is ok in my .env file but i still get my 502 Bad Gateway error when i try to access to that root.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb1rN.png)

i am expecting that when i type bwa.localhost:8080 i can see my website

Comment: Have you updated the `hosts` file too?